# Why do I need an \hbox inside \vcenter to make it work?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, tex-core

I want to vertically center an object in an equation. I thought: "Ok, `\vcenter` is the way to go." But I don't understand (not even from [the TeX primitives reference](http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#vcenter-rp)), why I need an `\hbox` inside my `\vcenter` to make it work. And also, is this a bad approach? Is there a better alternative?

See the following MWE (1: no modifiers, 2: `\vcenter{...}`, 3: `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation}
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\end{equation}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{equation}
\vcenter{\rule{5cm}{5cm}}
\end{equation}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{equation}
\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{5cm}{5cm}}}
\end{equation}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you start a paragrah inside a vbox (or vcenter) the lines will be broken to `\hsize` which is `\textwidth` here which is wider than you want. You should use a tabular which will vertically centre and look more like latex. All LaTeX box and rule commands consistently start a paragraph (so `\rule` here) but TeX primitives like `\hbox` do not.

Comment: Could you expand a little bit more? The thing is that we don't need to start a pragraph or what? Can there be a construction where `\vcenter{..}` doesn't need `\hbox` inside?

Comment: @Manuel Yes, for example when there's `\halign` inside :)

Comment: @Manuel anything that stacks in vertical mode: `\hbox` `\hrule` `\halign` `\vskip`, ... but the point is that in latex you should  never be in this position as you shouldn't be in a `\vcenter`

Comment: @tohecz Okey. `\begin{tabular}{c}..\end{tabular}` is the way to go :)